# ManagementObjectSearcher not finding Network Drive using LogicalDisk filter in VS

Tags: visual-studio, wmi, wmi-query

Trying to capture the serial number of a remote disk drive. PowerShell will list the mapped network drive using Win32_LodicalDisk; Windows Management Instrumentation Tester lists the drive; The drive is listed in HKCU\Network; But running ManagementObjectSearcher in C# module in VS finds every other logical disk but the only mapped drive I have.

Some other successes with WMI resulted from opening up the firewall for WMI local input on the remote PC, which is a laptop. But, still no discovery of the machine as a mapped device. Also tried release execution and using executable for bitness of the PC instead of any PC.

```
        ConnOpt = new ConnectionOptions();
        ConnOpt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        var msc = new ManagementScope(@"root\cimv2", ConnOpt);
        ObjectQuery oqQry;
        if (null != driveCode)
        {
            oqQry = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");
            //oqQry = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType = 4");
            //oqQry = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_MappedLogicalDisk ");
            try
            {
                oWMI = new ManagementObjectSearcher(msc, oqQry);
                if (null != oWMI) {
                    foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in oWMI.Get())
                    {
                        if(null!= wmi_HD["ProviderName"])sProvidr = wmi_HD["ProviderName"].ToString();
                        if (null != wmi_HD["VolumeName"]) sProvidr = wmi_HD["VolumeName"].ToString();
                        if (null != wmi_HD["Description"]) sProvidr = wmi_HD["Description"].ToString();
                    }

                }
```

**In conclusion:**

An additional discovery came from using WMI in VBA. However, the results were the same, absence of mapped drive discovery within logical disk. So, the work around will be using registry data when the mapped drive can't be discovered.

The same inquiry posted to MSDN netted an additional WMI search parameter using ASSOCIATORS OF. Aside from that lesson the solution would point to using PowerShell scripts within C#. That helps but, for now my work around will suffice and I don't know if the same approach will work in VBA. Its time to move on.

Comment: Please provide snippets of code for what you have already tried https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a bit of what I've tried including a couple of the lines commented out that were tried as well.